# $f$ continous at $x_0$ $⇒\lim_{h→0}∫_{x_0}^{x_0+h}\frac{f(t)}{h}=f(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, integration, continuity

The function $f:ℝ→ℝ$ is continuous on $x_0\inℝ$. 
Prove using the definition of a Darboux Integral that 
$$\lim_{h→0}∫_{x_0}^{x_0+h}\frac{f(t)}{h}=f(x_0)$$

I'm a first grade math student following an analysis course. The book that is used is [Elementary Analysis by Ross](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-0-387-90459-7).

**Definitions**

1. The upper Darboux sum $U(f,P)$ of $f$ with respect to a partition $P$ is the sum 
   $$U(f,P)=∑_{k=1}^nM(f,[t_{k-1},t_k])(t_k-t_{k-1})$$
2. The lower Darboux sum $L(f,P)$ of $f$ with respect to a partition $P$ is the sum 
   $$L(f,P)=∑_{k=1}^nm(f,[t_{k-1},t_k])(t_k-t_{k-1})$$
3. $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ ⇔ $∀ε>0,∃δ>0,(|x-x_0|<δ ⇒ |f(x)-f(x_0)|<ε)$
4. Let $f$ be a function defined on on $J-\{a\}$ for some interval $J$ containin $a$, and let $L$ be a real number. Then $ \lim_{x→a}f(x)=L$ if and only if
   $$∀ε>0,∃δ>0,(0<|x-a|<δ⇒|f(x)-L|<ε)$$

Can someone check if this is an correct proof ?

**Proof**

Let $ε>0$. Then there exist an $δ>0$, such that: $|x-x_0|<δ ⇒ |f(x)-f(x_0)|<ε$. 
Let $0<|h-0|<δ$. If $x\in[x_0,x_0+h]$ then $x\in(x_0-δ,x_0+δ)$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<ε$, then $|\frac{f(x)}{h}-\frac{f(x_0)}{h}|<\frac{ε}{h}$.

Therefore: 
\begin{equation*} 
m ( \frac{f(x)}{h},[x_0,x_0+h]) \cdot (x_0+h - x_0) ≥ \frac{f(x_0)-ε}{h} \cdot h = f(x_0)-ε
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*} 
M ( \frac{f(x)}{h},[x_0,x_0+h]) \cdot (x_0+h - x_0) ≤ \frac{f(x_0)+ε}{h} \cdot h = f(x_0)+ε
\end{equation*}

Therefore we can conclude that for a partition $P$ of $[x_o,x_0+h]$

\begin{equation*} 
f(x_0)-ε< L(f,P)≤∫_{x_0}^{x_0+h}\frac{f(t)}{h}≤U(f,P)<f(x_0)+ε 
\end{equation*}
QED

Comment: @Kasper As you can see I deleted my comment when I noticed that. To the OP, this seems pretty much correct to me

Comment: You might want to explain why $U(f,P)<f(x_0)+\epsilon$ (and also the inequality for the lower sum). But, you should find this easy.

Comment: @DavidMitra Here are some things I still doubt:
1. Shouldn't I say:
\begin{equation*} 
U(f,P) ≥ m ( \frac{f(x)}{h},[x_0,x_0+h]) \cdot (x_0+h - x_0) > \frac{f(x_0)-ε}{h} \cdot h = f(x_0)-ε
\end{equation*}

Instead of ≥ and > switched.


2. $x\in[x_0,x_0+h]$ doesn't work when h<0. Shouldn't I say something about that ?

Comment: I mean $L(f,P)$ instead of $U(f,P)$

Comment: @Kasper Yes, you need to worry about the sign of $h$. Perhaps it's easiest to do the left and right hand limits separately.  In your inequalities, for $h>0$, you want to say $L(\color{maroon}{f/h},P)> f(x_0)-\epsilon$ and $U(\color{maroon}{f/h},P)< f(x_0) +\epsilon$.

Comment: @Kasper Concerning 1., yes, you want the inequalities as you have (but with $L(f/h,P)$ instead of $U(f,P)$ and $h>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct. Here is a simpler, but not by definition, proof:

Let $F(h)=\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(x)\, dx$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ by the 1st FTC, $F^{\prime}(0)=f(h)$. Therefore,,
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(h)-F(0)}{h}=F^{\prime}(0)=f(x_0)$$
Again, this is a not by definition proof.